# Atom snippets in assembly not working

Tags: atom-editor, code-snippets

So I use Atom, and I use Snippets. I used it before for writing `cpp` code, and it worked perfectly. Now I wanted to add few Snippets for assembly language.

Here is the relevant part of my `snippets.cson`:

```
'.source.s':
  'movl':
    'prefix': 'movl'
    'body': 'movl ${1:SOMETHING}, ${2:%eax}'
```

Snippets for `cpp` work perfectly, but snippets for assembly do not work. I've got `.s` file, and when I type movl, it appears on the popup, but then I use tab, it just writes down `movl`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from a look at [language-assembly](https://github.com/oliverkeeble/atom-language-assembly/blob/master/README.md), the scope should be `.source.assembly` (it can be more specific, e.g. `.source.assembly.asm.x86.intel`).

When in doubt, you can always [expose the current scope](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-find-the-current-scope/2223) from the command palette.